# Android: AsyncTask - onPostExecute never gets called

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-asynctask

I have been browsing about this I am not finding the answer that suits my problem. But i would like on execute **onPostExecute** but it never gets called.

I send in a *timestamp*, unixtime, to the server and I get a *list* in return (ArrayList). Then I want to work with that *list* in onPostExecute. I do get the list though.

- I send in Long
- I want to work with that list, I think.
- I want to return that list

Thats why I do 'Long, ArrayList, ArrayList'

Could use a little help, thanks!

```
    private class getMealsByDayConnection extends AsyncTask<Long, ArrayList<CalanderMeal>, ArrayList<CalanderMeal>>          {

    protected ArrayList<CalanderMeal> doInBackground(Long... params) {

        CalendarService service = CalendarServiceFactory.getCalanderService();
        try {
           return service.getMealsByDay(params[0]);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<CalanderMeal> result){
        CalendarAdapter adapter = null;
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the service.getMealsByDay is returning ? Have you tried logging or putting a breakpoint to ensure that they are in fact functioning correctly ?

Comment: Yes it is returning a list. But its empty, not null. But i would still like to render it in a specific form in listView. I need A list, if you see what I mean.

Comment: Are you sure you are not getting a NullPointerException ? Because your adapter is null

Comment: Its never called so i dont get a NullPointerException hehe ;)

Comment: Add @Override in doInBackground() method and type "System.out.println("I am running says onPostExecute");" after adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: @SindriÞór and let me know if the message "I am running syas onPostExecute" gets displayed?

Comment: The name of the class should be GetMealsByDayConnection, see Java naming conventions.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute(Result)), the method will not be called if the task is cancelled. So perhaps your task is being cancelled since an empty list is returned? Or the onPostExecute(result) doesn't work because result is an empty list? You might be able to catch this by overriding onCancel().

Btw, you did call the async task from within the main UI thread and start the task with the getMealsByDayConnection.execute() method, right?

Comment: Yes i have thought about that possibility. Soon to be ill finnished my addToList function and we will see :)

Comment: I edited my post to include two other possibilities; let me know if they are helpful.

Comment: Yes thats true. I call 'new getMealsByDayConnection.execute(unixtime)'

Answer (score 0):

i think you are calling asyncTask with

```
getMealsByDayConnection.doInBackground(params);
```

if you are executing like this , task will execute in main thread and the doInBackground() function alone will execute.

you should execute asynctask like this,

```
getMealsByDayConnection.execute();
```